# How can I open pdfs in firefox using evince (not acrobat)?

Tags: firefox, evince, firefox-extensions

I already installed mozplugger

```
sudo apt-get install mozplugger
```

Then I changed the pdf part of /etc/mozpluggerrc into the following:

```
application/pdf:pdf:PDF file
application/x-pdf:pdf:PDF file
text/pdf:pdf:PDF file
text/x-pdf:pdf:PDF file
    repeat noisy swallow(evince) fill: evince "$file"
    ACROREAD()
    repeat noisy swallow(kpdf) fill: kpdf "$file"
    repeat noisy swallow(Xpdf) fill: xpdf -g +9000+9000 "$file"
    repeat noisy swallow(okular) fill: okular "$file"
    GV()
    repeat noisy fill exits: evince "$file"
```

Of course I setted the application settings for pdf to Mozplugger.

Sometimes it works but mostly it dosn't. I don't know why. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox 15 has a pdf reader integrated with it, it is disabled by default,  type about:config, search for "pdfjs.disabled" and set it to "false" double click it. Then go to edit preferences then go to applications search for pdf extension then select to open within firefox that should work for you.

Comment: Sorry, there's a problem, sometimes I see the message: "The PDF document will not be displayed correctly eventually". So this is not so bad but I wouldn't have this problem when I used evince so a solution with evince would be better.

Comment: I have check on this and the document seems to be viewed the same in evince as it is in the native pdf in firefox I believe that this is an issue that will be worked out in the next release of firefox.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is dated. The PDF viewer in Firefox is now enabled by default.

On the other hand, Mozplugger still doesn't reliably enable Firefox show PDFs using Evince. I would particularly like that because it would permit substituting Windows-only fonts like Century Gothic with free (and available) ones like URW Gothic L by means of fontconfig.

Oh well. My workaround when a document appears less than optimally in Firefox's PDF viewer is to press the download icon and choose "Open with: Document Viewer (default)".

My version numbers: Ubuntu 13.10, Firefox 26, Mozplugger 1.14, Evince 3.10.