# How to work with and manage many open PDFs in Ubuntu

Tags: pdf

It is no secret that working with many open PDFs in Ubuntu using the Evince Viewer is a huge mess and needs some serious overhaul (or maybe not?). Despite the discussion if Evince should support tabbing to solve the problem, I am curious what people have come up with in the meantime to work around this problem and make Ubuntu more productive. One solution I found is to run Evince in Chrome or Firefox that support tabbing:

- [How can I open pdfs in firefox using evince (not acrobat)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183774/how-can-i-open-pdfs-in-firefox-using-evince-not-acrobat)

What other tricks you got?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want an app for the *web browser* or for the *Ubuntu desktop*?

Comment: He wants to know ways of working with multiple open PDFs, no matter what. No confusions there.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Chrome just google docs to open the file.  I have a right click option in my context menu that opens the pdf or doc in google docs.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docs-pdfpowerpoint-viewer/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn

There are a few different extensions for doing this so find the one you like the most.

Now all you need to do is save them to a location with a url which could be Ubuntu One or even Google Drive, but it isn't officially supported.  Media Fire Express gives you URLs for files you upload.

Any way good luck...hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

open firefox

**write**:

about:config

**Find and change the value**

```
browser.preferences.inContent
```

from False to ----> **True**

**Find and change the value**

pdfjs.disabled

from False to ----> **True**

Comment: You should review your answer. Tell us the objective of your method.

Comment: @Lucio, I think this answer points to the built-in PDF file viewer of Firefox aka `pdf.js`. And users can view several pdf files, each in its own tab. I use it. I'm not sure that `pdf.js` needs to be enabled now; I think it's shipped activated by default in recent versions of Firefox..